# Why I am getting error while concatenating variables in output in C++?

Tags: c++

I am trying to concatenate output variables in C++
In my code there are some calculations and when I am printing the output of the variables I am getting error.

My code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<math.h> 
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   
       string name;
       cout<<"Enter the name of the borrower: ";
       cin>>name;

       float mortage_blanace;
       cout<<"Enter the mortage balance: ";
       cin>>mortage_blanace;

       float interest_rate;
       cout<<"Enter the annual interest rate: ";
       cin>>interest_rate;

       float current_monthly_payment;
       cout<<"Enter the current monthly payment: ";
       cin>>current_monthly_payment;

       float extra_monthly_payment;
       cout<<"Enter the extra monthly payment: ";
       cin>>extra_monthly_payment;

       cout<<"\n"; 

       int new_payment = current_monthly_payment+extra_monthly_payment;
       float i = (interest_rate/100)/12;
       int current_duration_in_months =  (log(current_monthly_payment/(current_monthly_payment/i)-mortage_blanace))/(log(1+i));
       int new_duration_in_months = (log(new_payment/(new_payment/i)-mortage_blanace))/(log(1+i));
       float current_interest = (current_monthly_payment*new_duration_in_months)-mortage_blanace;
       float new_interest = (new_payment*new_duration_in_months)-mortage_blanace;
       int current_duration_years = current_duration_in_months/12;
       int current_duration_months = current_duration_in_months%12;
       int new_duration_years = new_duration_in_months/12;
       int new_duration_months = new_duration_in_months%12;
       float savings = current_interest-new_interest;
       string fees;
       
       cout<<mortage_blanace + "      " + mortage_blanace;
       cout<<"\n";

   } 
     
    return 0;
}
```

But I am getting following error:

```
Untitled1.cpp: In function 'int main()':
Untitled1.cpp:58:30: error: invalid operands of types 'float' and 'const char [7]' to binary 'operator+'
        cout<<mortage_blanace + "      " + mortage_blanace;
```

How can I get concatenated output in C++ like the one I want?!

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: why not just `cout<<mortage_blanace << "      " << mortage_blanace;`? Instead of trying to concatenate a float with an array of characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [insertion operator](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ostream/ostream/operator%3C%3C/) (`<<`) to display values to standard output instead of trying to concatenate a float with an array of characters.

```cpp
cout << mortage_blanace << "      " << mortage_blanace << endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use string concatenation, i.e. `+` directly for a `float` and a `std::string`. You can use insertion operator as Tanner Dolby said or if you need to use `+` you can convert the `float` value to `std::string` using `std::to_string`. You can then use string concatenation.

```
       cout<<to_string(mortage_blanace) + "      " + to_string(mortage_blanace);
       cout<<"\n";
```